# How can I add internal padding to the plot area of my highchart/highstock chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart that needs to fit to end to end of a touch screen. I have been able to do this by reducing the margin of the left and right side of the chart to fit it's container.

```
 chart: {
    marginTop: 0,
    marginBottom: 0,
    marginLeft: 0,
    marginRight: 0,
 }
```

I also want to keep a space or padding between the yAxis labels and the plot data, so I have used the x-value of the yAxis label to try and prevent the data from overlapping it. I then added marginRight to make it visible:

```
 chart: {
    marginRight: 45,
 }
 yAxis: {
    labels: {
      align: 'right',
      x: 30
    },
 }
```

The problem is that this forces the navigator to shrink.

[image]

How can I have my chart:

- stay end to end of the containing div
- with yAxis plot-area padding (to keep plot points from overlapping the yAxis labels)
- and retain the navigator width to have a full width of the container?

[jsFiddle to showcase the example](https://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan002/oebj5087/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set the `chart.marginRight` property, because (as you can see now, and you can read in the documentation) it produces a free space between the chart edge and plot area, so that's why the navigator has also the same with like the other chart elements.

In order to achieve the effect you need, just make all margins will be set to `0`, and then set the `width` property equal to e.g. `95%` on every yAxis and xAxis (in this case three axes). It should give you what the result you need.

```
  chart: {
     margin: 0
  },
  yAxis: [{
    labels: {
      align: 'right',
      x: 30
    },
    height: '60%',
    lineWidth: 2,
    resize: {
      enabled: true
    },
    width: '95%'
  }, {
    labels: {
      align: 'right',
      x: 30
    },
    top: '65%',
    height: '35%',
    width: '95%',
    offset: 0,
    lineWidth: 2
  }],
  xAxis: {
    width: '95%'
  },
```

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/5zxodeb0/

Comment: Thanks for this!!